# "gradle files have changed since last project sync" message always shows up

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In my Android Studio

> gradle files have changed since last project sync

message always shows up even after gradle sync is done and my application is not deploying on physical device or Emulator!

Comment: the same issue here, could any one help?

Answer (score 6):

I figurout that this happens after change PC time. lol

Comment: message is disappear in the next day

Comment: Works like a charm, I wonder why Windows sometimes is displaying wrong time.

Comment: @mariozawa, thank you. Actually they disappear when your current date is greater than the date before changing PC time.

Comment: I've run "find . -exec touch {} \; " in the project's directory and it got fixed.

Comment: Saved my life, thanks alot... One more way to get rid of this is by deleting .gradle folder.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe you try to change the module gradle dependencies, added a line with compile?
If u have done that, One of your'e changes that you've made are not good.try to find whice one of them. 
If this isn't your'e problem try to open new project copy the gradle module into your project and sync again.

Answer (score 0):

if this problem happened when you compile c/c++,and Here is a solution.

First:  make sure your `jni`directory is at the same tree level as `java`
[jni directory tree level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yigla.png)

Second:

```
 sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = []//delete this line
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
    }
}
```